# Desktop/laptop user experience of different flavors

Tags: distribution-choice

Would a desktop user see any big difference running Fedora or Ubuntu?

I know that the package management is (still) different and that Ubuntu has abandoned Unity in favor of Gnome, so could it be that desktop versions are converging (in all aspects)? Including the package managers, maybe.

In general, I wonder whether we need so many different dists: for science, for multimedia and so on. Linux can be adapted to any use by a single command of `apt install <list of packages for science/media>`, so what's the point of so many different flavors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environments will appear very similar as by default they are both GNOME 3 based. (Ubuntu, not K/L/Xubuntu/etc)

The application bases are equivalent across the board. Web browsers, office productivity, etc will be virtually identical. The UI based GNOME Software manage will appear the same but the back-end will use `apt` or `yum`.

You may run into certain software packages not being available from the built in repositories on both platforms. Most of these will have alternative installation methods. Edge cases where the software was developed specifically on one or the other do exist however.

As to why Linux is so fractured with all these flavours available, that's subjective. The answer comes somewhere between "because there can be" and "not all computers are created equal" so the end user has to make a choice.